# Tab widget height set with percentage

Tags: android, xml

I have a `TabHost`,and want to set `Tabwidget` height 7%  of the screen height in `Xml`.
Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:weightSum="1"` in your `TabHost`

And add `android:layout_weight="0.2"` & `android:layout_height="0dp"` to `TabWidget`

and  `android:layout_weight="0.8"` & `android:layout_height="0dp"` to `FrameLayout`

which will make the **TabWidget**  `20%` and the **FrameLayout** to `80%` in height respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set width or height in percent.
You have to get the screen size link [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions) and do the math.